# What is the right way to add 'app.MapControllerRoute' in program.cs of a Scaffolded Area in ASP.NET 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I am creating an Area using Scaffolding for my project. As there is no `startup.cs` file is ASP.NET 6, I suppose I have to add it in the `program.cs` file. What is the right way to do that and is it any of the followings:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "Admin",
      pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
      pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
})
```

**OR**

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
   name: "Admin",
   pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapControllerRoute(
   name: "default",
   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
   name: "Admin",
   pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

OR

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "Admin",
      pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
      pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Both the above methods are correct in Asp.net 6 application, you can use one of them.

After configuring the areas route and creating the controller in the areas, please remember to add the `[Area]` attribute to the controller. like this:

[image]

More detail information about routing, see [Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-6.0).